# How to install Cinnamon desktop environment on top of Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Pardon my ignorance, but I'm relatively new to Linux and unable to find a sufficient answer to this question elsewhere.  I'm looking to install the Linux Mint environment on top of Ubuntu, preferably with the option of switching between the normal Ubuntu Gnome environment and Mint (like you would switch between Gnome and KDE).

Two questions:

1. Is this even possible?
2. If so, what's the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:**

Turns out when I asked this question I didn't know how to ask it correctly. What I wanted was not all of Linux Mint but rather just the Cinnamon desktop environment.

The Cinnamon desktop environment used in Linux Mint can be installed with Ubuntu using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon nemo
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who comes to this question looking for how to install the Mint desktop environment on top of Ubuntu.

Comment: Is virtualization a possibility?

Comment: Both are gnome, you only need a theme, an icon set, and the mint tools.

Comment: The main visual difference is the desktop. You can install the Cinnamon desktop in Ubuntu, like you can install KDE or Gnome. So yes, if you just want the Mint desktop look and feel, you can install it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Since the question got reopened, can you add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Linux Mint isn't related to Ubuntu the way Kubuntu and the like are, (Direct offshoots etc...) you unfortunately cannot install the Linux Mint environment on top of the Ubuntu DE like you can with say, Kubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu etc...You can do a second partition and install Linux Mint on that and subsequently choose between them at system boot with the GRUB menu but that's the extent of what you can do in regards to running Linux Mint on Ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to switch like Gnome and KDE. You need to make a fresh install for Linux Mint and in the end of the installation, grub (boot loader) will do the things in spite of you.

You can select the Operating Systems after the BIOS section on Grub window.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, you can't do it like that. However, you can modify your Ubuntu to ACT like Linux Mint. To get the Mint Menu, and other Mint tools, add the WebUpd8 PPAs for each one. it's a slog, but you probably don't need all of them